# Chirp wasm DOMException

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, webassembly, chirp

Given the following code (based on [chirp sample code](https://developers.chirp.io/docs/getting-started/wasm#receiving-data))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <script src="https://public.chirp.io/wasm/3.1.0/chirpSdk.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const { Chirp, toAscii } = ChirpSDK;
      console.log("Chirp", Chirp);
      Chirp({
        key: 'MY_CHIRP_APP_KEY',
        onReceived: data => {
          if (data.length > 0) {
            console.log(toAscii(data))
          } else {
            console.error('Decode failed')
          }
        }
      }).then(sdk => {
        console.log("sdk", sdk);
        let rc = sdk.start()
        if (rc !== 0) console.warn(sdk.errorToString(rc))
        rc = sdk.send('hello')
        if (rc !== 0) console.warn(sdk.errorToString(rc))
      }).catch(console.error)
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get this working on Firefox 67.0 (64-bit) on Linux Mint, while on Chrome 75.0.3770.80 (64-bit) I get a DOMException with no additional text.

It seems to fail in the `Chirp` function, and is rejected before the `then` method is called. Why would this fail?

Comment: Instead of doing `console.error`, can you try `console.dir` so that maybe a stack trace can be seen?

Comment: @Bergi Great suggestion. I then get: `code: 8,
message: "Requested device not found",
name: "NotFoundError"`. I realized no microphone was attached and the problem was solved